# Zipped Data in S3 that needs to be used for Machine Learning on EMR or Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I have huge CSV files in the zipped format in S3 storage. I need just a subset of columns from the data for Machine learning purposes. How should I extract those columns into EMR then to Redshift without transferring the whole files?

My idea is to process all files into EMR then extract subset and push the required columns into Redshift. But this taking a lot of time. Please let me know if there is an optimized way of handling this data.

Edit: I am trying to automate this pipeline using Kafka. Let say a new folder in added into S3, it should be processed in EMR using spark and stored into redshift without any manual intervention.

Edit 2: Thanks for input guys, I was able to create a pipeline From S3 to Redshift using Pyspark in EMR. Currently, I am trying to integrate Kafka into this pipeline.

Comment: If you are comfortable with python / r / spark you can do it in EMR. I believe for ML you would anyway need to load the data into an EMR or EC2..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- Create an **external table in Amazon Athena** (An AWS Glue crawler can do this for you) that points to where your data is stored
- Use `CREATE TABLE AS` to select the desired columns and store them in a new table (with the data automatically stored in Amazon S3)

Amazon Athena can handle gzip format, but you'll have to check whether this includes zip format.

See:

- [CREATE TABLE - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html)
- [Examples of CTAS Queries - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html)
- [Compression Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/compression-formats.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am trying to automate this pipeline. Let say a new folder in added into S3, it should be processed and stored into redshift without any manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to materialise a subset of the file columns in a table in Redshift then one option you have is Redshift Spectrum, which will allow you to define an "external table" over the CSV files in S3.

You can then select the relevant columns from the external tables and insert them into actual Redshift tables.

You'll have an initial cost hit when Spectrum scans the CSV files to query them, which will vary depending on how big the files are, but that's likely to be significantly less than spinning up an EMR cluster to process the data.

[Getting Started with Amazon Redshift Spectrum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html)